# How can I remove style from android's text selection contextual actionbar (actionmode)

Tags: android, xml

Android's text selection contextual actionbar has inherited some style from my app that makes it look funny.  I want to remove this styling and use the default.  How can I achieve this?  Preferably in xml rather than programmatically.

[image: I want to revert to the default styling of this text selection contextual actionbar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by first discovering the right terminology.  It is the text selection contextual actionbar but in the documentation it is referred to as the ***actionmode*** bar.

I did the following to style the bar as I please.

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#c9c9c9</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/MyActionMode</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

and then...

```
<!-- ActionMode styles -->
<style name="MyActionMode" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
</style>
```